# proper word form required

Tags: word-form, word-formation

pls kindly check the proper form of the below words outlined in the text below. I cannot check the answers, but the person who passed had "disgusted" and "lacking" marked as wrong. Initially the forms were "disgust, lack, public".

I am completely ***disgusting*** that this miscreant who dishonestly took money from the elderly is not being brought to trial. He’s obviously ***lacking*** in any human compassion and should be ***publically*** condemned.

thanks in advance)

Answer (score 1):

Should be "disgusted" rather than "disgusting". Something "disgusting" *causes* disgust.

The "not being brought to trial" is the thing that is "disgusting".

"Lacking" is correct.

"Publically" should be "publicly".

Comment: thanks! Hence the test itself is wrong, right? As it says "disgusted" and "lacking" are wrong answers.

Comment: The person marking the test was definitely wrong. The speaker _feels_ disgust, they don't cause it in someone else!